# JFugue - slides / pitch bends

Tags: java, jfugue

Using JFugue 5.0, how would one go about creating pitch bends and slides like those in guitar pro?

I've tried using CC65, but it doesn't seem to work on a guitar patch.  I've looked at the documentation, and it doesn't say explicitly how this is done.  I could use microtonal notation, but something tells me there's a better way.

Loading up an example midi and examining it as a pattern file doesn't give me any clues because of the way the midi messages are organized, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JFugue 5.0, controller events are specified using the function name :CON (including the colon) with parameters, like this:

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("V0 I[Guitar] C5 :CON(65,127) D4");
```

Where the first parameter is the controller number, and the second parameter is the value for the controller.